# Android SQLITE DB lost all datas

Tags: android, database, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I know this  is a very weird problem. I was using sqlite for storing transaction datas on a machine which works on android OS. The application have multiple tables and performs multiple db read/write operations. App often experiences app crash. And its found that the app lost all the datas on app crash sometimes.

*I'm using a **Database handler class which extends Sqlite Open helper** for performing all db operations.
This is the link of the tutorial I followed. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

**DatabaseHandler Class**

```
    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static DatabaseHandler mInstance = null;
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 77;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "chillarMachine";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TABLE_OPERATIONAL_DEVICE_DATA= "operational_device_data";
private static final String TABLE_DEVICE_INFO= "device_info";
private static final String TABLE_USER= "user";
private static final String TABLE_BLOCKED_CARDS_INFO= "blocked_cards_info";
private static final String TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA= "user_permission_dataa";
private static final String TABLE_ATTENDENCE_TYPE= "attendence_type";
private static final String TABLE_ATTENDENCE_DATA= "attendence_data";
private static final String TABLE_TRANSACTION_TYPE= "transaction_type";
private static final String TABLE_SUCCESS_TRANSACTION= "success_transaction";
private static final String TABLE_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION= "payment_transaction";
private static final String TABLE_PAYMENT_TYPE= "payment_type";
private static final String TABLE_RECHARGE_DATA= "recharge_data";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY_LIST= "category_list";
private static final String TABLE_ITEM_STOCK= "item_stock";
private static final String TABLE_ITEM_LIST= "item_list";
private static final String TABLE_SALES_ITEM_LIST= "sales_item_list";
private static final String TABLE_ITEM_SALE_TRANSACTION= "item_sale_transaction";
private static final String TABLE_FEES_TRANSACTIONS= "fees_transactions";
private static final String TABLE_FEES_LIST= "fees_list";
private static final String TABLE_FEES_STRUCTURE= "fees_structure";
private static final String TABLE_LIBRARY_BOOK_TRANSACTION= "library_book_transaction";
private static final String TABLE_ITEM_TYPE= "item_type";

private static final String TABLE_REFUND_TRANSACTION= "refund_transaction";




// Common Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_MACHINE_ID= "machine_id";
private static final String KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP= "server_timestamp";
private static final String KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID= "transaction_type_id";
private static final String KEY_TRANSACTION_ID= "transaction_id";
private static final String KEY_CARD_SERIAL= "card_serial";
private static final String KEY_ITEM_ID= "item_id";
private static final String KEY_CATEGORY_ID= "category_id";
private static final String KEY_SALES_TRANS_ID= "sales_trans_id";
private static final String KEY_BILL_NO= "bill_no";
private static final String KEY_TOTAL_AMOUNT= "total_amount";
private static final String KEY_FEES_TRANS_ID= "fees_trans_id";
private static final String KEY_FEES_ID= "fees_id";


//Device info columns names
private static final String KEY_SERIAL_NO= "serial_no";
private static final String KEY_SCHOOL_ID= "school_id";
private static final String KEY_SCHOOL_NAME= "school_name";
private static final String KEY_SCHOOL_PLACE= "school_place";
private static final String KEY_DEVICE_LAST_TRANS_ID= "device_last_trans_id";
private static final String KEY_MAIN_SERVER_URL= "main_server_url";
private static final String KEY_MAIN_UPLOAD_PATH= "main_upload_path";

//User table Columns names
private static final String KEY_USER_ID= "user_id";
private static final String KEY_USER_NAME= "user_name";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD= "password";

//Blocked cards info table Columns names
private static final String KEY_BLOCKED_CARDS_ID= "blocked_cards_id";


//User permission data table Column names
private static final String KEY_PERMISSION_ID= "permission_id";

private static final String KEY_PERMISSION= "permission";

//Attendence Type table Column names
private static final String KEY_ATTENDENCE_TYPE_NAME= "attendence_type_name";

//Attendence data table column names
private static final String KEY_ATTENDENCE_DATA_ID= "attendence_data_id";

private static final String KEY_IN_OUT= "in_out";
private static final String KEY_ATTENDENCE_TYPE_ID= "attendence_type_id";

//Transaction type table column names
private static final String KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME= "transaction_type_name";

//Success transaction table column names
private static final String KEY_PREV_BALANCE= "prev_balance";
private static final String KEY_CURRENT_BALANCE= "current_balance";
private static final String KEY_TIME_STAMP= "time_stamp";


//Payment transaction table column names
private static final String KEY_AMOUNT= "amount";

//PAyment type table column names
private static final String KEY_PAYMENT_TYPE_NAME= "payment_type_name";

//Recharge data table column names
private static final String KEY_RECHARGE_ID= "recharge_id";
private static final String KEY_RECHARGE_AMOUNT= "recharge_amt";
private static final String KEY_RECHARGE_TIME= "recharge_time";
private static final String KEY_PAYMENT_TYPE_ID= "payment_type_id";



//Fees list table column names

//Fees structure table column names
private static final String KEY_FEES_STRUCTURE_NAME= "fees_structure_name";


// Table Create Statements
// Operational device data table create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_OPERATIONAL_DEVICE_DATA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_OPERATIONAL_DEVICE_DATA + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_LAST_TRANS_ID
        + " TEXT," + KEY_MACHINE_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_LAST_MACHINE_TRANS_TIME
        + " DATETIME," + KEY_LAST_SERVER_TRANS_TIME + " DATETIME," + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";


private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DEVICE_INFO = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_DEVICE_INFO + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_MACHINE_ID
        + " TEXT," + KEY_SERIAL_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_SCHOOL_ID
        + " TEXT," +KEY_SCHOOL_NAME+ " TEXT," +KEY_SCHOOL_PLACE+ " TEXT," +KEY_DEVICE_LAST_TRANS_ID+ " TEXT," + KEY_MAIN_SERVER_URL + " TEXT," + KEY_MAIN_UPLOAD_PATH + " TEXT" + ")";


private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USER + "("
        + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_BLOCKED_CARDS_INFO= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_BLOCKED_CARDS_INFO + "("
        + KEY_BLOCKED_CARDS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_CARD_SERIAL + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA + "("
        + KEY_PERMISSION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER,"
       + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_PERMISSION + " INTEGER," + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ATTENDENCE_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTENDENCE_TYPE + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ATTENDENCE_TYPE_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ATTENDENCE_DATA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ATTENDENCE_DATA + "("
        + KEY_ATTENDENCE_DATA_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TRANSACTION_ID + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_IN_OUT + " INTEGER," + KEY_ATTENDENCE_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TRANSACTION_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TRANSACTION_TYPE + "("
        + KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SUCCESS_TRANSACTION = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_SUCCESS_TRANSACTION + "(" + KEY_TRANSACTION_ID + " VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_USER_ID
        + " INTEGER," + KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_PREV_BALANCE
        + " FLOAT," + KEY_CURRENT_BALANCE + " FLOAT," + KEY_CARD_SERIAL + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME_STAMP + " DATETIME," + KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME" + ")";

  public static DatabaseHandler getInstance(Context ctx) {

    // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
    // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.

    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DatabaseHandler(ctx);
    }
    return mInstance;
}



public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_OPERATIONAL_DEVICE_DATA);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DEVICE_INFO);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BLOCKED_CARDS_INFO);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ATTENDENCE_TYPE);



}

// Adding new User................................................................................................................
void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_USER_ID,user.getUser_id());
    values.put(KEY_USER_NAME, user.getUser_name()); // User Name
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, user.getPassword()); // User Password
    values.put(KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP,user.getServer_timestamp()); //server timestamp

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
User getUser(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_USER_ID,
                    KEY_USER_NAME, KEY_PASSWORD ,KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP}, KEY_USER_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));
    // return contact
    return user;
}
// Getting All Conta
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    // Select All Query


    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUser_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            user.setUser_name(cursor.getString(1));
            user.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            userList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
    db.close();
    // return contact list
    return userList;
}

// Updating single user
public int updateUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_USER_NAME, user.getUser_name());
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_USER, values, KEY_USER_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getUser_id()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, KEY_USER_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getUser_id()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getUserCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
public  void deleteAllUser(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_USER);
    db.close();
}







// USER PERMISSION DATA ...........................................................................................................



// Getting single contact
User_Permission_Data getUserpermission(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA, new String[] { KEY_PERMISSION_ID,KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID,
                    KEY_USER_ID, KEY_PERMISSION,KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP }, KEY_PERMISSION_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    User_Permission_Data contact = new User_Permission_Data(
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)),cursor.getString(4));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<User_Permission_Data> getAllUserspermission() {
    List<User_Permission_Data> permissionList = new ArrayList<User_Permission_Data>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            User_Permission_Data userpermission = new User_Permission_Data();
            userpermission.setPermission_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            userpermission.setTransaction_type_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            userpermission.setuser_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            userpermission.setPermission(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
            userpermission.setServer_timestamp(cursor.getString(4));

            // Adding contact to list
            permissionList.add(userpermission);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
    db.close();

    // return contact list
    return permissionList;
}

// Updating single user
public int updateUserpermission(User_Permission_Data userpermissiondata) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valuespermission = new ContentValues();
    valuespermission.put(KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID, userpermissiondata.getTransaction_type_id());
    valuespermission.put(KEY_USER_ID, userpermissiondata.getuser_id());
    valuespermission.put(KEY_PERMISSION, userpermissiondata.getPermission());
    valuespermission.put(KEY_PERMISSION_ID, userpermissiondata.getPermission_id());
    valuespermission.put(KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP, userpermissiondata.getServer_timestamp());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA, valuespermission, KEY_PERMISSION_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(userpermissiondata.getuser_id()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteUserpermission(User_Permission_Data user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA, KEY_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getuser_id()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getUserCountpermission() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
public  void deleteAllUserpermission(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_USER_PERMISSION_DATAA);
    db.close();
}


public void userPermission(int userId){
    System.out.println("CODMOB:permiss");
    String MY_QUERY = "SELECT transaction_type_name FROM transaction_type INNER JOIN user_permission_dataa" +
            " WHERE user_permission_dataa.user_id=?";
    System.out.println(MY_QUERY);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});


    TransactionType transactionType=new TransactionType();

    System.out.println("CODMOB:cursor "+ transactionType.getTransaction_type_name());

    cursor.close();

}


public List<Payment_Transaction> getAllpaytransactiontoUp() {
    List<Payment_Transaction> paytrans = new ArrayList<Payment_Transaction>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION+" where "+KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP+" = ''";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Payment_Transaction paytranss = new Payment_Transaction();

            paytranss.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            paytranss.setbillno(cursor.getString(1));
            paytranss.settrans_id(cursor.getString(2));

            paytranss.setamount(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(3)));


            paytranss.setserver_timestamp(cursor.getString(4));

            // Adding contact to list
            paytrans.add(paytranss);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
//        db.close();
    // return contact list
    return paytrans;
}




public List<Refund> getAllRefundtoUp() {
    List<Refund> liblist = new ArrayList<Refund>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REFUND_TRANSACTION+" where "+KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP+" = ''";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Refund sl = new Refund();
            sl.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            sl.setTrans_id(cursor.getString(1));
            sl.setOrig_trans_id(cursor.getString(2));
            sl.setAmount(cursor.getFloat(3));
            sl.setserver_timestamp(cursor.getString(4));

            // Adding contact to list
            liblist.add(sl);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
    // return contact list
    return liblist;
}



public List<Payment_Transaction> getallPaymentbyBill(String transid) {
    List<Payment_Transaction> feetransact = new  ArrayList<Payment_Transaction>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION+" where "+KEY_TRANSACTION_ID+" = "+"'"+transid+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Payment_Transaction itemsss = new Payment_Transaction();
            itemsss.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            itemsss.setbillno(cursor.getString(1));
            itemsss.settrans_id(cursor.getString(2));
            itemsss.setamount(Float.valueOf(cursor.getString(3)));
            itemsss.setserver_timestamp(cursor.getString(4));

            // Adding contact to list
            feetransact.add(itemsss);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor

    // return contact list
    return feetransact;
}




public List<Success_Transaction> getAllsxstoupNew() {
    List<Success_Transaction> successtrans = new ArrayList<Success_Transaction>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SUCCESS_TRANSACTION+" where "+KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP+" = '-1'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Success_Transaction successss = new Success_Transaction();
            successss.settrans_id(cursor.getString(0));
            successss.setuser_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            successss.settarans_type_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            successss.setprevious_balnce(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(3)));
            successss.setcurrent_balance(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(4)));
            successss.setcard_serial(cursor.getString(5));
            successss.settime_stamp(cursor.getString(6));
            successss.setserver_timestamp(cursor.getString(7));
            // Adding contact to list
            successtrans.add(successss);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
    // return contact list
    return successtrans;
}



public List<Item_Sale> getAllitemsaletoUpNew() {
    List<Item_Sale> feetransact = new ArrayList<Item_Sale>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEM_SALE_TRANSACTION+" where "+KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP+" = '-1'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Item_Sale itemsss = new Item_Sale();
            itemsss.setsale_trans_id(cursor.getString(0));
            itemsss.settransaction_id(cursor.getString(1));
            itemsss.setbill_no(cursor.getString(2));
            itemsss.settot_amount(cursor.getString(3));
            itemsss.setserver_timestamp(cursor.getString(4));

            // Adding contact to list
            feetransact.add(itemsss);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
//        db.close();
    // return contact list
    return feetransact;
}

public List<Sales_Item> getAllsaletoUpNew() {
    List<Sales_Item> liblist = new ArrayList<Sales_Item>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SALES_ITEM_LIST+" where "+KEY_SERVER_TIMESTAMP+" = '-1'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Sales_Item sl = new Sales_Item();
            sl.setSales_item_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            sl.setsales_trans_id(cursor.getString(1));
            sl.setitem_id(cursor.getString(2));
            sl.setitem_quantity(cursor.getString(3));
            sl.setamount(cursor.getString(4));
            sl.setserver_timestamp(cursor.getString(5));


            // Adding contact to list
            liblist.add(sl);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
//        db.close();
    // return contact list
    return liblist;
}



public String userLogin(String uName,String uPass){
    String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + KEY_USER_NAME + "='" + uName +"'AND "+KEY_PASSWORD+"='"+uPass+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor!=null&&cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String uID=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID));

        System.out.println("LOGIN USER ID : "+uID);

        cursor.close();
        return uID;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return "false";


}

public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
{
    String password="";
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, null, KEY_USER_NAME + "=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
        cursor.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        return "exception";
    }
    return password;
}
```

}

Comment: Please share the code and how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: capture app crash logs and share.

Comment: I have added a sample of my database handler class.

Answer (score 0):

try to run your app in emulator and check database after crash to see if it's actually destroyed/recreated or data is present and your methods are not extracting data (eg. wrong keys)

can't help more without logs

Comment: I cant run this in emulator bcause this is a machine which uses RFID module. I have implemented crashlytics tool and the only crashes I get from this machine are Illegal state exceptions, SqliteDisk io Exceptions etc. any help?

Comment: cant you fake/disable RFID on emulator? just to debug database issues

Comment: There lies the problem. No transactions can be made without RFID card reading. I mean, all the transactions are completed and written to db only after reading an RFID card. Hence, no RFID means, no DB .

Comment: Could this problem happen if i miss to close the db/cursor after transactions? will that result in the loss of whole records?

Comment: i don't think is waiting you to close cursor to commit the transaction, but im not so sure. also i don't think it will screw all your db. what about adding a temporary debug button that dump to log your db, so you can investigate its status after a crash

Comment: Well ,the last time it occured was just some minutes ago. the machine was  in idle state and then when tried to use ,unfortunately the db was long lost.  :(